# formatting dates in Grails

Tags: grails, date, formatting, gsp

I have a domain class in Grails with a field journeyDate. journeyDate is defined like this:-

Date journeyDate

then in my list.gsp I display the date like this:-

${fieldValue(bean:journeyInstance, field:'journeyDate')}

And it is displayed in the following format:-

2009-08-19 17:12:00.0

does anyone know how I can format this on the list.gsp so that it doesn't display the seconds? (I don't want to change the way it is stored in the database)

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at the [date format tag](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRAILS/GSP+Tag+-+formatDate)?

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
${fieldValue(bean:journeyInstance, field:'journeyDate').format("dd MM, yyyy")}
```

or

```
${journeyInstance.journeyDate.format('dd MM, yyyy')}
```